# Java - YouTube API - setPublishAt on video leads to "400 Bad Request - invalidVideoMetadata"

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to save a video via the YouTube API. Basically it is already working fine, just for one exception: If I try to set the `status.setPublishAt()` I get

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
  "domain" : "youtube.video",
  "location" : "body",
  "locationType" : "other",
  "message" : "The request metadata is invalid.",
  "reason" : "invalidVideoMetadata"
} ],
"message" : "The request metadata is invalid."
}
```

The code is as follows:

```
YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = M_YOUTUBE.videos().list("snippet,status").setId(_dbVideo.getYoutubeId());

VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

List<Video> videoList = listResponse.getItems();
if (videoList.isEmpty()) {
    return false;
}

Video video = videoList.get(0);
VideoStatus status = video.getStatus();

status.setPrivacyStatus(_dbVideo.getPrivacyStatus()); // "private"

String sPublishedAt = _dbVideo.getPublishedAt();
// sPublishAt is in ISO 8106: "2016-10-28T10:01:00.000+02:00"
if (sPublishedAt != null && sPublishedAt != "") {
    // this line leads to the bad request.
    status.setPublishAt(new DateTime(sPublishedAt));
} else {
    status.setPublishAt(null);
}

VideoSnippet snippet = video.getSnippet();

String sTitle = _dbVideo.getTitle();
String sDescription = _dbVideo.getDescription();
String sTags = _dbVideo.getTags();

...

snippet.setTitle(sTitle);
snippet.setDescription(sDescription);
snippet.setTags(tagList);
snippet.setCategoryId(_dbVideo.getCategoryId());

YouTube.Videos.Update updateVideosRequest = M_YOUTUBE.videos().update("snippet,status", video);         
updateVideosRequest.execute();
```

For the uploading process I am using mostly the same code and it is working there. If I decide not to set the `publishAt` property with a date and instead set it to null it is working fine as well. Am I missing something?

Update: 
The beheviour only occurs if the video was set to `public` once. If i decide to set it back to `private` and set a new `publishAt` i get the `BadRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to sent all the status values, otherwise the update method will think you are trying to empty them. You have send setPrivacyStatus and publishat. But you should send all other parameter to your request. Also, if you send publishat time too close to current time it will show badRequest (400) invalidPublishAt. try to put 60 mins. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried it, but with no success. Anyways, this would not explain why it is actually working with just setting the privacystatus and publishedAt to null.

Comment: @PAWL if api does not show privacystatus and publishedAt, that means it is null. and when you send your request to server, without changing it. it works correctly.

Comment: @PAWL does it again send 400 badRequest

Comment: 1. if i only change the privacy status from private to public and comment the change of publishAt out it works as well.   2. yes, the error stays the same.